# SELECT users that appear daily

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question that appears easy on the surface but I'm finding challenging, hence the request for help. I have a table with two columns:

```
table: USERS

USER_ID | LOGGED_IN_DATE
  001   | 2015-05-01
  002   | 2015-05-01
  003   | 2015-05-01
  001   | 2015-05-02
  ...
```

What I need is a query that will return all of the IDs that were present every day for a given week, say 2015-05-01 through 2015-05-07. Not just anytime during the week, but there must be a record for that user every day. I need the fastest and most concise query possible. Any ideas?

What I tried already:

1. Sub-queries
2. Union Queries
3. self-join

With no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Aggregation is probably the easiest way:

```
select u.user_id
from users u
where u.LOGGED_IN_DATE >= '2015-05-01' and u.LOGGED_IN_DATE < '2015-05-08'
group by u.user_id
having count(distinct date(u.LOGGED_IN_DATE)) = 7;
```

If the field is really a date with no time, then you don't need the `date()` function in the `having` clause.

Comment: This didn't work exactly. I built a table and put user id 01 in every day from 2015-05-01 through 2015-05-07. I put user id 02 in every day except 2015-05-05. When I ran this query, both came up. Only user id 01 should have since 02 did not have a record daily.

Comment: @TonyD . . . Please set up a SQL Fiddle.  Only User 01 should come up in your case.

Comment: their site appears to be down right now...looking at our queries they appear similar yet I still get incorrect results with yours.

Comment: @TonyD . . . The logic is pretty simple.  The `where` clauses chooses records between two dates with 7 days in-between.  The `having` counts the number of distinct dates in the period.  When that is 7 then all days are accounted for.

Comment: @TonyD i'm not sure why you are having issues with this query, it should work fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3caf0/1

Comment: @TonyD Gordon's query is correct. Look at this example on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f22ae/8. Tweak the data as you like and you will notice correct results.

Comment: You are right - when I first ran it inside of mysql it did not give me the results I was expecting. Now that I'm testing it, the query works great. Thank you @GordonLinoff.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it, instead of trying to do some complicated SQL query, I asked myself what does it mean to be online daily. It means that the number of unique dates in that given time period should equal 7. So this query I think works well:

```
select sub.user_id, sub.count 
FROM (select user_id, count(1) as count from users where logged_in_date >= '2015-05-01' AND logged_in_date < '2015-05-08' group by user_id) sub 
where sub.count = 7;
```

Any thoughts/comments?

**UPDATE**:

This should handle any number of logins at the day level:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, count(1) AS total 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, logged_in_date 
         FROM users 
           WHERE logged_in_date >= '2015-05-01' 
             AND logged_in_date < '2015-05-08' 
               ORDER BY logged_in_date) sub 
   GROUP BY user_id 
   HAVING total = 7;
```

As well as @Gordon's answer:

```
SELECT u.user_id
  FROM users u
   WHERE u.LOGGED_IN_DATE >= '2015-05-01' 
      AND u.LOGGED_IN_DATE < '2015-05-08'
       GROUP BY u.user_id
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(u.LOGGED_IN_DATE)) = 7;
```

I like his better though. Good job.

Comment: What about users who logged in multiple times in a day?

Comment: Good point - here is my updated query:

    select distinct user_id, count(1) as total FROM (select distinct user_id, logged_in_date from users where logged_in_date >= '2015-05-01' AND logged_in_date < '2015-05-08' ORDER BY logged_in_date) sub GROUP BY user_id HAVING total = 7;